# EntityFramework insists on storing value in database with fixed length

Tags: entity-framework

For some reason, when I store values to my database, it insists on making it exactly 6 characters long. So when I insert the string "red" it actually gets stored as "red   " (with three extra spaces at the end).

I know what caused this. I created the database field as nchar(6). This was a mistake. But even after changing it to nvarchar(6), it still adds 3 extra spaces to "red". I also tried deleting the table and recreating it from scratch. This did not help. I tried an insert statement with "red" as the value to go into the field in question. This worked. So this suggested to me the problem is in EntityFramework.

So I move to my application. It's an MVC application using EntityFramework. I update the model from the database. I examine the table of interest in the model:

[image]

The trouble field is Color. I look at the properties:

[image]

I see that "Fixed Length" is set to true. I set it to false. I try again. Still adding extra space. I try setting fixed length to none. Still adding extra space.

What more does a guy have to do to stop it from adding extra space? What other gazillion spots are there to configure?

Comment: You'r using DB first, so technically, if the db is ok, your model is ok, are you sure you successfully changed it to nvarchar(6) ? Do you have the good connection string in your config files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing the XML directly, or deleting the table from the model, then updating from the database to add it again.

Comment: Well, that certainly worked. I changed <Property Name="Color" Type="nchar" MaxLength="6" /> to <Property Name="Color" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="6" /> and presto! The question is... why? Why would I--EVER--have to do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know why really.  I'm guessing it can't detect all types of changes, or can't tell what you meant to override and what is new.  I just remember pulling my hair out for an hour over the same thing.